# Parallel programming for tasks in main function - c++

Tags: c++, c++17

is it possible to define two tasks and let them work parallel in C++? I found something about parallel funtcions, but not about parallel tasks in main function like that:

```
int main()

  // task 1
  int a = 0;
  for(int i = 0; i < 150; i++){
      a++;
      std::cout << a << std::endl;
      // do more stuff
  }

  // task 2
  int b = 0;
  for(int i = 0; i < 150; i++){
      b++;
      std::cout << b << std::endl;
      // do more stuff
  }
}
```

Race conditions etc. can't occur.
Thank's for helping !

Comment: Yes you can do that, though this is super broad at the moment. You can use threads, coroutines, async, ....

Comment: In C++17, you can package your ""tasks"" into a lambda or `std::packaged_task` and use `std::async`.

Comment: @CoryKramer You can use _"threads, coroutines, async, ..."_ without functions in `main`? Do you have a reference? I would expect a lambda (unnamed function) at least. But as far as I understand the question OP want's parallel code blocks without functions.

Comment: @jabaa Right they would obviously have to refactor their code to turn those "tasks" into something callable like a packaged_task, a lambda, etc. How they do that refactoring will obviously depend on what parallell mechanism they settle on

Comment: @CoryKramer But in that case I would consider your comment _"Yes you can do that,"_ as wrong because it's not possible without functions.

Comment: @jabaa `std::thread t1([](){ /* code in task 1 */}); std::thread t2([](){ /* code in task 2 */}); t1.join(); t2.join();` This would be one way. This fragment doesn't contain any function definitions.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik But there are two functions and in my understanding OP doesn't want a function. That should be clarified at least for me.

Comment: If this were parallelized I'd be worried about cout interleaving the output or even individual characters so I'd also encourage the use of `std::osyncstream`

Comment: @jabaa No, there aren't any functions defined here, as the term is understood by the C++ language grammar.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik So you would say a lambda is not a function? It's defined as _"unnamed function object"_ on [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda)

Comment: @jabaa It's [an expression](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.prim.lambda), not a [function definition](https://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.fct.def). In any case, it's unclear why "without functions" is a requirement for the problem at hand.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Yes, it's an expression that creates a function object and at the end two parallel functions are called. That's not what OP wants according to my understanding.

Comment: @jabaa The OP doesn't say anything about function objects. I'm also not sure what you mean by "parallel functions"; I'm not familiar with the term, and the C++ standard doesn't define it.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik That's what I'm saying. How could you answer this question with yes or no if the terms _"parallel function"_ or _"parallel task"_ are not specified? According to my understanding OP doesn't want to start two functions in parallel. But without two functions (created as lambda, functor, or explicitly declared function) it's not possible. OP shows two code blocks in `main`, calls them _"tasks"_ and wants to run them in parallel without functions from `main`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can run the two in parallel, using `std::async` and lambdas. Here is an example:

```cpp
int main()
{
  auto f1 = std::async(std::launch::async, [](){
  // task 1
  int a = 0;
  for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
      a++;
      std::cout << a << std::endl;
      // do more stuff
  }      
  });    

  auto f2 = std::async(std::launch::async, [](){
  // task 2
  int b = 100;
  for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
      b++;
      std::cout << b << std::endl;
      // do more stuff
  }
  });
                       
  f1.wait();
  f2.wait();
}
```

(You'll get messed console output from this, because you need to guard access to the console with mutex or another similar resource.)

Comment: Thanks, that helped me a lot ! Let me ask another question please..:
In the tasks i now want to read one and the same file and write for each tasks a other file. The files are realy big so i thought that would be speed up my code.. but it is a bit slower than before. Do you have an idea why?

Comment: @Chris sounds like a different topic. Please post this as a new question and also shared the code you're having. In principle, not every concurrency/parallelization implies speedup. Synchronization to shared data and context switches between threads may introduce an execution overhead that will make the total execution time be greater.